# My Google Blogger Post Blocked By robot.txt

Tags: seo, blogger

I have created a google blogger site & I have 27 posts there. I also submit my site in google search console. The problem is robot.txt file blocked my 26 posts. I checked by a robot.txt tester and it allowed to all my post But google search console page showed me 26 posts blocked by the robot.

How can I solve this? Please help me.

Here is some screenshot.

Screenshot One

[image: Screenshot One]

Screenshot Two

[image: Sreeenshot Two]

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your robots txt to allow them fetch and render as google within the WMT. Google will index those pages within a couple of days.